# How can I access custom properties of a view (or partial view)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP .NET WebForms, it was possible to create properties and methods in WebControl pages that were accessible from the host page. Is this possible in MVC?

I'd like to add custom properties to a partial view, render it on the main view and then have the main view access those properties. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can have many solutions. F.e. you can use complex main view model, that have a partial view model property:

```
public struct PartialViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public int Bar { get ; set; }
}

. . .

public struct MainViewModel
{
    public double Baz { get; set; }

    public PartialViewModel Qux { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can build `MainViewModel` in an action's code:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    var model = ModelRepostiory.GetById(id);
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel
    {
        Baz = model.Baz,
        Qux = new PartialViewModel
        {
            Foo = model.Partial.Foo,
            Bar = model.Partial.Bar,
        },
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**MainView.cshtml**

```
@model MainViewModel
. . .
<div>
<p>Additional info:</p>
@Partial("partial", Model.Qux)
</div>
```

**PartialView.cshtml**

```
@model PartialViewModel
<p>Foo: @Model.Foo</p>
<p>Bar: @Model.Bar</p>
```

Comment: Oh nice, I really like this approach. Is it possible to return the model of the main view from the controller? Something like: `var partialViewValue = View.Current.Model.Qux.Foo`

Comment: As I can see, it's not possible cause a controller's action should return `ActionResult`, that is HTML, or JavaScript, or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I meant from the controller. The user clicks a button on the main view, a method on the controller fires. In that method, can I determine the current model without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Your problem hasn't simple solution in HTTP, cause HTTP is stateless. You could store a last loaded model in a [session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.session(v=vs.100).aspx), and then read this model from a session, not from database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ViewBag will help you in this

You can set ViewBag properties with

```
ViewBag.MyProperty = "this is a string";
```

and then retrieve them in other parts of the view.

Answer (score 0):

This only makes sense in an event based system. The state of a control changes and the container needs to react to those changes.

In ASP.NET MVC the container main view 
 passes the data to its partials. If a partial needs to change the state of the application it posts the changes to a controller action. The controller action then supplies the changed model to the main view and the the contained partials.